# Update row in Access table using OleDb

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I try to update a row in my Access, my code is running fine and I have to Exception, But is nothing change un my database

This is my method it calls from a form in a Winform project

```
   public static void UpdateNextReportNumber(int machineNumber, string reportNumber)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (OleDbConnection openCon = new OleDbConnection(localConnectionString))
                    {
                        string saveStaff = "UPDATE [Calibration] " +
                            "SET [NextReportNumber]=@report " +
                            "where [MachineNumber]=@machine";

                        using (OleDbCommand querySaveStaff = new OleDbCommand(saveStaff))
                        {
                            querySaveStaff.Connection = openCon;
                            querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine", 16);
                            querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report",2);//Convert.ToInt32(reportNumber.Remove(0, 3)) + 1
                            openCon.Open();
                            int recordsAffected = querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

this is how my Calibration table looks like 
[image]

my code pass this line

```
int recordsAffected = querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But in recordsAffected I have value 0

I have no idea what to do

I tried to execute using Access this query

```
UPDATE [Calibration]
SET [NextReportNumber]=2
where [MachineNumber]=36
```

And its work fine

I also used

```
 public static void AddCalibration(Calibration calibration)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OleDbConnection openCon = new OleDbConnection(localConnectionString))
                {
                    string saveStaff = "INSERT into [Calibration] ([MachineNumber] ,[LastCalibrationDate] ,[NextCalibrationDate])" +
                        "VALUES (@MachineNumber, @LastCalibrationDate, @NextCalibrationDate)";

                    using (OleDbCommand querySaveStaff = new OleDbCommand(saveStaff))
                    {
                        querySaveStaff.Connection = openCon;
                        querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineNumber", calibration.MachineNumber);
                        querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastCalibrationDate", calibration.LastCalibrationDate);
                        querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextCalibrationDate", calibration.NextCalibrationDate);
                        openCon.Open();
                        int recordsAffected = querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

And it works fine also...

Thanks for help...

Comment: This is a repetitive question, OLEDB for Access does not support named parameters. see [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776991/2398630) i.e for an answare

Comment: @Sion.D.P so how do my insert work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OleDb parameters are not recognized by their name but by their position in the parameters collection. You should simply change the line order of your parameters

```
querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report",2);
querySaveStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine", 16);
```

In your current query the report's parameter is used in the Where statement not in the update part and of course nothing is updated because there is no record with *WHERE MachineNumber = 2*

Indeed, in OleDb you usually specify the parameters placeholder with a single *?* not with the *@something* syntax, but Access, probably for easier portability with Sql Server accepts also the @ syntax, still the positions in parameter's collection should be the correct one expected in the query text.